# Disposing Maybe in RxAndroid

Tags: kotlin, rx-android

I'm new to the reactive world so please bear with me if what I'm saying is wrong (please correct me!).

So I was searching through google and here for something similar but I think I haven't seen anyting around the avenue of what I've done. I'm using the Rx2Firebase library to get some data from my database using the `RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent` method and I couldn't wrap my head around how I would go about disposing the Observable I made. So this method returns a Maybe and I want to dispose of that Maybe after executing my code but I'm unsure as to how (read on below as to why).

**My current code looks something like this:**

```
private fun getUserStatus(callback: () -> Unit) {

RxFirebaseDatabase
    .observeSingleValueEvent(myQuery,(entry::class.java))
    .subscribe ({ item
     myEntry = item
     callback()
   },{ e
     Log.e("Error", e.message)
   })
}
```

From what I've read, observables are assigned to a `Disposable` variable and then I think that variable would be disposed? something like `var disposable: Disposable = <Insert my code above for calling Firebase>` and you would do so (from what I've read) inside `onDestroy`. My question would be how would I do this if my code isn't executed within an Activity or a Fragment? I couldn't just add a `dispose()` at the end of my code after `.subscribe` since that would just end the call before it finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to dispose of the `Maybe` after your code was executed. You should dispose any observable, whenever you need the cancel the underlying action to. Since you're using Android, the action is triggered from within some lifecycle aware component. This could be `Activity`, `Fragment` or `Service`. If you trigger the call from a `BroadcastReceiver` you should start a service to do this instead.

For any of these components you have a method `onDestroy` where you can dispose of the observable. The only thing you have to make sure is to propagate the `Disposable` up to this level:

```
private fun getUserStatus(callback: () -> Unit): Disposable =
    RxFirebaseDatabase
      .observeSingleValueEvent(myQuery,(entry::class.java))
      .subscribe ({ item ->
          myEntry = item
          callback()
      },{ e ->
          Log.e("Error", e.message)
      })
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. It worked as intended. If there any super noobs out there (like me) I just checked onDestroyView() and onDestroy() by logging the isDisposed property to check that it was disposed.

Comment: Correction to what I last said... don't do it on onViewDestroy if you're using tabs. That would end up with a crash if you're other tabs are also observing the same thing.